# Using exceptions as default arguments in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, default-parameters

I'm writing a function in Kotlin to retrieve items of type `T` from a database.

The user can specify an action to be invoked if no matching results are found, otherwise an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown:

```
fun get(
    ...,
    onNoneFound: () -> T = throw IllegalStateException("No matching results found")
): T {
    ...

    return when (results.size) -> {
        0 -> onNoneFound.invoke()
        1 -> ...
        else -> chooseResult(...)
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that whenever the function is invoked, it seems that the `IllegalStateException` is thrown before the function body is executed.

In a way, that makes sense, and I suppose a workaround could be:

```
fun get(
    ...,
    onNoneFound: (() -> T)? = null
): T {
    ...

    return when (results.size) -> {
        0 -> if (onNoneFound == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("No matching results found")
        } else {
            onNoneFound.invoke()
        }
        1 -> ...
        else -> chooseResult(...)
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant/preferable solution to this problem - ideally where I do not have to make the function nullable and do a null check later. Is there a way of doing this with Kotlin's default argument syntax?

**Edit:**
It occurred to me that I can use the elvis operator for the null check which does make the code more elegant:

```
onNoneFound?.invoke() ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("No matching results found")
```

But I'm still curious if Kotlin has a built-in way of doing this without the null check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't build the exception directly. Try:

```
fun get(
    ...,
    onNoneFound: () -> T = { throw IllegalStateException("No matching results found") }
): T {
    ...

    return when (results.size) -> {
        0 -> onNoneFound.invoke()
        1 -> ...
        else -> chooseResult(...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `throw IllegalStateException(...)` is a perfectly fine expression of type `() -> T`, just as it is an expression of any other type; but it throws the exception immediately, what you want is a lambda which will throw the exception *when invoked*. And that's `{ throw IllegalStateException(...) }` in Kotlin, as 
Roger Lindsjö's answer says.